# YAGO entity details

Tags: uses-of-open-data, linked-data, rdf, ontology, dbpedia

I recently came across an article where they have mentioned that YAGO has more entities than DBpedia. It also mentions that **"Recently, a new version of YAGO has been released, which also accounts for temporal and spatial information associated with entities."**

Thus, I am interested in checking the entity details of 'support vector machine' in YAGO. Where can I find these entity details in YAGO knowledge-base? (E.g., Like in DBpedia: http://dbpedia.org/page/Support_vector_machine).

Please let me know how to get these YAGO details of entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAGO [Demo page](https://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/databases-and-information-systems/research/yago-naga/yago/demo/) lists two possible ways:

- [Explore YAGO with our graph browser](https://gate.d5.mpi-inf.mpg.de/webyago3spotlx/SvgBrowser?entity=%3CSupport_vector_machine%3E) (YAGO3)
- [Explore YAGO with our ontology browser](https://gate.d5.mpi-inf.mpg.de/webyagospotlx/Browser?entity=%3CSupport%5Fvector%5Fmachine%3E) (YAGO2)

You can find what you need using [query builder](https://gate.d5.mpi-inf.mpg.de/webyagospotlx/WebInterface?L01=&L0R=rdfs%3Alabel&L02=%22Support+vector+machine%22%40eng&L0T=&L03=&L0L=&L04=&L05=&L11=&L1R=&L12=&L1T=&L13=&L1L=&L14=&L15=&L21=&L2R=&L22=&L2T=&L23=&L2L=&L24=&L25=&L31=&L3R=&L32=&L3T=&L33=&L3L=&L34=&L35=&L41=&L4R=&L42=&L4T=&L43=&L4L=&L44=&L45=).

There also exists [SPARQL endpoint](https://linkeddata1.calcul.u-psud.fr/sparql?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=describe+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fyago-knowledge.org%2Fresource%2FSupport_vector_machine%3E&format=text%2Fx-html%2Btr&timeout=0&debug=on).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer. What will you recommend out of DBpedia and YAGO to build a concept hierarchy?

Comment: Well, what can you do with [these results](https://linkeddata1.calcul.u-psud.fr/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=%0D%0APREFIX+yagor%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fyago-knowledge.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT+*+%7B%0D%0A++yagor%3ASupport_vector_machine+%3Fp+%3Fo+.%0D%0A++FILTER+%28isIRI%28%3Fo%29+%26%26+%28%3Fp+%21%3D+yagor%3AlinksTo%29%29+%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fx-html%2Btr&timeout=0&debug=on)... Dozens of undistinguishable `linksTo` and `rdf:type`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I would like use properies such as broader, subject. Can you please tell me whether you received these data from YAGO or DBpedia?

Comment: They are from YAGO (2?). Try to [edit](https://linkeddata1.calcul.u-psud.fr/sparql?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=%0D%0APREFIX+yagor%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fyago-knowledge.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT+%2A+%7B%0D%0A++yagor%3ASupport_vector_machine+%3Fp+%3Fo+.%0D%0A++FILTER+%28isIRI%28%3Fo%29+%26%26+%28%3Fp+%21%3D+yagor%3AlinksTo%29%29+%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fx-html%2Btr&timeout=0&debug=on) this query, if you want.